# Images are not stored in the local using python cv

Tags: python, flask

I have a python code which open the web cam and convert the image automatically into cartoonic image.

The captured image is not storing in the local and also instead of my website i dont know why its opening the separate window
let me know how to solve this

Thanks in Advance!!!

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
import cv2
from time import sleep

app = Flask(__name__)

key = cv2. waitKey(1)
webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
sleep(2)

def gen_frames():
    while True:
        try:
            check, frame = webcam.read()
            print(check) #prints true as long as the webcam is running
            print(frame) #prints matrix values of each framecd
            cv2.imshow("Capturing", frame)
            key = cv2.waitKey(1)
            if key == ord('s'):
                cv2.imwrite(filename='saved_img.jpg', img=frame)
                webcam.release()
                print("Processing image...")
                img = cv2.imread('saved_img.jpg')
                gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                #gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                gray = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 5)
                edges = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,
                cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 9, 8)
                # Cartoonization

                color = cv2.bilateralFilter(img, 9, 250, 250)
                cartoon = cv2.bitwise_and(color, color, mask=edges)
                #blurred = cv2.bilateralFilter(img, d=7, sigmaColor=200,sigmaSpace=200)

                cv2.imwrite(filename='saved_img.jpg', img=cartoon)
                print("Image saved!")
                break

            elif key == ord('q'):
                webcam.release()
                cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                break

        except(KeyboardInterrupt):
                print("Turning off camera.")
                webcam.release()
                print("Camera off.")
                print("Program ended.")
                cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                break

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    #Video streaming route. Put this in the src attribute of an img tag
    return Response(gen_frames(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')


@app.route('/')
def index():
    """Video streaming home page."""
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Index file
Here the sample html file

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Live Streaming Demonstration</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8  offset-lg-2">
            <h3 class="mt-5">Live Streaming</h3>
            <img src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}" width="100%">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can spot 2 issues: your `except` untypically has `()`, if they are not intentional remove it, i.e. replace

```
except():
```

using

```
except:
```

Indentation levels for `try` and corresponding `except` are different, they should be same (number of spaces before `try` and corresponding `except` should be equal)

Comment: Sorry Daweo the code is changed now its working fine but instead of my website i dont know how the cam is opening in seperate window and the image is also not storing in local